# Is there any way of giving Global Search functionality to the Name field on Transaction Records?

Tags: transactions, netsuite, record

Good afternoon all,
Just wondering if anyone knew of a way to give Global Search functionality to the Name field on Transaction Records?

*Eg. This would be to make it easier to search for Customers when entering a new Sales Order*

That way users would only need to search for part of a name, or for a field on the Customer record that is Global Search compatible.

Appreciate your help, thank you!

Cheers,
Giles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would most probably be a custom suitelet, which would post a value back to the name field when the result is selected.
There's no system funtionality for making the field an equivalent to the Global Search.